# What is meaning of "Sets $_ for each item in LIST in turn" in perl function returning a scalar?

Tags: perl, iterator

The Perl [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) documentation says that the function `true` "Sets $_ for each item in LIST in turn".

That makes it sound like an iterator, but I see no way to use it as such.
E.G.

```
use List::AllUtils qw(first any true);
@strings = `dir`;
printf "%i item(s) start with 1", true { substr($_,0,1) eq '1' } @strings;
```

prints 18.

Trying it in list mode, as if it were grep:

```
@ones = true { substr($_,0,1) eq '1' } @strings;
```

still returns just an integer.

If there is no way to retrieve the individual matches, what does the comment about `$_` mean?

The same comment is used on many other List::Util and List::MoreUtils functions which return scalars, eg, `all`, `any`, etc.

Comment: "If there is no way to retrieve the individual matches, what does the comment about $_ mean?" It means you can do `true { /foo/ } @strings` instead of `true { $somevar =~ /foo/ } @strings`. This is exactly how `grep`, `map`, and `for` work: `$_` is aliased to each element in turn.

Answer (score 0):

The [complete definition](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/List-AllUtils-0.09/lib/List/AllUtils.pm#true_BLOCK_LIST) in the manual states that:

> **true BLOCK LIST**
>
> Counts the number of elements in LIST for which the criterion in BLOCK
>   is true. Sets `$_` for each item in LIST in turn
>
> ```
> printf "%i item(s) are defined", true { defined($_) } @list;
> ```

So it does result in a  scalar, representing the number of elements from
*LIST* in which the content of the *BLOCK* is true. Each element will be
assigned to `$_` and the code in *BLOCK* will be executed. If the result
is true,  it will  add to the  internal count; until  the whole  list is
finished and the total sum of true results is returned.

Comment: so it is equivalent to `scalar grep BLOCK LIST`

Comment: @ysth Apparently yes. I can't notice any difference, not sure if I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 0):

$_ is the "current context's value"... in your example, the block is executed with $_ set to each element from @strings.

You then test for equality of "1".  So the output of the block is a list (possibly containing 18 elements) each with only "1" in each item.  And then filter for only true values - of which all of them will be true - which results in the scalar-count of true elements (aka 18).

It appears you might be are in need of the "schwartzian transform" - which can capture tuples (instead of single values) per iteration, which could allow your print to access each value of $_... but it would also require a "for" or similar.

Comment: I should add... could you expand on your use-case?

Comment: So the $_ is entirely local to the routine, and unavailable to the caller? If so, what's the purpose of making a point of it in the docs? Or is it meant to warn you that it will wipe out any prior $_ setting ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to get the matched elements for a list, don't use this List::AllUtils thing, just use the perl 'grep' builtin (which is not the same as the grep command line program).

Something like this

```
my @matches = grep { substr($_,0,1) eq '1' } @strings;
my $num_matches = @matches;
```

Comment: Although I agree that there's no reason to use `List::MoreUtils::true` over `grep`, this doesn't answer the OP's question, which was: "If there is no way to retrieve the individual matches, what does the comment about $_ mean?"